# how can i update a model's field from another model in django?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

my models.py is :

```
class clients(models.Model):
    client_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True )
    '
    '
    money = models.IntegerField(default = 0)


class transfermoney(models.Model):
    first_client_id = models.IntegerField()
    second_client_id = models.IntegerField()
    amountofmoney = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

my serializers.py is :

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = clients
        fields = ('__all__')

 class moneytransfer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 class Meta:
        model = transfermoney
        fields = ('__all__')
```

my views.py is :

```
class transferingmoney(APIView):
        def post(self,request):
            serializer = moneytransfer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

i'm using django rest framework , and what i want is ,everytime when i make a post request into "transfermoney" model , it take the "first_client_id" and search for it into the "client_id" in the "clients" model and add the "amountofmoney" from "transfermoney" model to the "money" field in "clients" model , and the same for the "second_client_id"

please how can i do that ?

Comment: You can write the custom logic in your view to do the correct addition and substraction on transfer for both clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the question of how to do it completely correct is too big to discuss it here. 
I will only answer your question.

But the thing I need to mention - store money amounts in Decimal fields, not in Integer - that's just bad practice. Something like:

```
models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

will do. Now, to the subject of the question.

First of all, I suggest you add custom 'validate()' method in your moneytransfer serializer and add checks on the client_ids there. You are using integer fields (for some reason I guess) in your transfermoney model instead of Foreign Keys. Because of that, the validate method of the serializeк won't check for you if these ids actually exist, so it's better to add some validation. Then it will be called in your View and return False if your custom checks will fail. If I understood it correctly you want something like:

```
class BillingRecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate(self, data):
        try:
            clients.objects.get(client_id = data['first_client_id'])
            clients.objects.get(client_id = data['second_client_id'])
        except clients.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("One of the clients does not exist")
    return data

    class Meta:
        fields = ('__all__')
        model = transfermoney
```

With this, you will be sure that both the clients are present in your DB. 
Then, you can do something like:

```
class transferingmoney(APIView):
        def post(self,request):
            data=request.data
            serializer = moneytransfer(data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                client_1 = clients.objects.get(client_id=data['first_client_id'])
                client_2 = clients.objects.get(client_id=data['second_client_id'])
                client_1.money -= data['amountofmoney']
                client_2.money += data['amountofmoney']
                client_1.save()
                client_2.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

You can also create a separate method for the logic I have added in the view to make code clear and reusable. Personally i'd prefer to override save() method of transfermoney model to do it there. And then it will be automatically called on the first save() of this model. But it all depends on what place you will be more comfortable with and what is the logic behind your code.

And I want to mention this is obviously not the right way to deal with money transactions, but describing the right way is way over the topic of the question and also there are a lot of examples out there.

P.S. I wrote the code right here, so there could иу some typos in it.

Comment: thank you "Igor Belkov" , but there are errors "Undefined variable" for "data" in client_1 , client_2  and for the amountofmoney (in the views class"transferingmoney"

Comment: @AhmadMardene fixed it

Comment: sorry for annoying you , it work , but now when i make a post request it start telling me : unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'str'

Comment: The types on the string: "client_1.money -= data['amountofmoney']" are wrong, do client_1.money -= decimal.Decimal(data['amountofmoney'])
You will also need to add "import decimal" in views.py